# Match rows and subtract columns

Tags: r, subtraction

I have 2 datasets having the same columns and different number of rows.

```
> dput(smalldf)
structure(list(X = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "F", 
"G"), class = "factor"), Y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L), Z = c(10L, 
20L, 30L, 60L, 70L)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))


> dput(bigdf)
structure(list(X = structure(1:7, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), Y = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L, 60L, 70L), Z = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L
)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I would like to match the similar rows and subtract the Y column. I know this is a quite simple task but I wasn't able to do it! should I be using `match()`? or some sort of `apply()` function here?

Comment: I think (E,X) should be 9 and not 3. `bigdf[rownames(smalldf), ] <- bigdf[rownames(smalldf), ] - smalldf`

Comment: Sorry Aurn seems like my edit has changed a lot about the question. Cheers

Comment: If you try and understand what that command does, then you can change it to fit your needs for the newly edited data with a little effort. We expect in SO that people learn from answers to their questions. So, I'll leave that task to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda a common problem. One way to do it in `base` R would be to use `match` as you suggest, like this with no `apply` in sight....

```
#  rows of bigdf that appear in smalldf, in order that they appear in smalldf 
idx <- match( rownames(smalldf) , rownames(bigdf) ) 

#  subtract rows of smalldf from bigdf for rows that appear in smalldf and rbind them with original rows from bigdf that do not appear in samlldf
result <- rbind( ( bigdf[ idx , ] - smalldf ) , bigdf[ -idx , ] )

#  Order the results
result <- result[ order( rownames(result) ) , ]
   X  Y  Z
A  3  2  5
B 10  3  7
C  0  0  6
D  5  3  4
E  9 -2 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the command is giving me a warning message and doing some weird things. The warning message is : Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : - not meaningful for factors. It is also changing the row names, I'll upload a simple dput :) so that you can try the command, I cannot understand what went wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Error404 sure, your data is not what you described in your edited question!!! This makes me VERY frustrated. X column is no longer some integer data, but it is now a factor of what was previously rownames. Change e.g. `rownames(bigdf)` to `bigdf$x` and do the same for `smalldf`. You will probably also have to convert `bigdf$x` and `smalldf$x` to character from factor.

Comment: Many apologies for this @SimonO101, I know this is quite annoying But I was trying to establish some proper example. Thanks for your answer