# Match Columns with rows and subtract from columns

Tags: r, cbind

my data looks like:

```
     >dput(mea)
     >structure(list(mea = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.5, 19.5)), .Names = "mea",
     row.names = c(NA,-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
     >dput(m1)
     >structure(list(t = c(5e-04, 0.001, 0.0015, 0.002, 0.0025, 0.003, 
     0.0035, 0.004, 0.0045, 0.005, 0.0055, 0.006, 0.0065, 0.007, 0.0075, 
     0.008, 0.0085, 0.009, 0.0095, 0.01, 0.0105, 0.011, 0.0115, 0.012, 
     0.0125, 0.013, 0.0135, 0.014, 0.0145, 0.015), a = c(21L, 13L, 
     17L, 20L, 19L, 9L, 11L, 16L, 28L, 10L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 27L, 30L, 
     6L, 29L, 22L, 24L, 5L, 25L, 18L, 26L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 23L, 8L, 7L, 
     2L), b = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
     1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c = c(19L, 25L, 14L, 
     18L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 20L, 17L, 13L, 28L, 2L, 29L, 15L, 26L, 
     12L, 24L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 22L, 27L, 21L, 23L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 30L), 
     `4` = c(NA, NA, NA, 18L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 20L, 17L, 13L, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA, NA), `17` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 26L, 12L, 24L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 22L, 
     27L, 21L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `<NA>` = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
     NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
     NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
     NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
     NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
     NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
     NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = "data.frame",
     row.names = c(NA,30L), .Names = c("t", "a", "b", "c", "4", "17", "<NA>"))
```

What I'm trying to do is to match the rownames of `mea` with the columnnames of `m1` and then subtract the appropriate value of `mea` from the whole column of `m1` (which matches the rowname of `mea`).

What I did is:

```
    mea1<-na.omit(mea)
    idx <- match(rownames(mea1) , 1:ncol(m1)) 
    m5 <- cbind((m1[,idx] - mea[idx,]), m1[,-idx])
```

I got this from the question asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077661/5681674

It does the trick, but the wrong way. It subtracts the second (last value) of `mea` from the first matched column of `m1` and the first value of `mea` from the second matched column of `m1`. But it should be in the correct order. 
I read somewhere that `cbind` works from end to front, is that the problem here? And how can I solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: Have you considered transposing mea (`t(mea)`) to make it easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to subtract a vector from a `data.frame` so the vector elements are getting recycled. It's not actually subtracting the elements in the "wrong" direction (i.e. `19.5` from column 1, and `7.5` from column 2). Instead, what's happening is `19.5` and `7.5` are being subtracted from each column in alternating order (because the elements are being recycled to fit the length of the column.

For example, check out `head((m1[,idx] - mea[idx,]))` compared to `head(m1[,idx])`. You'll see that row 4 is `-1.5` or `18 - 19.5` and row 5 is `-4.5` or `3 - 7.5`.

To fix this you can use `mapply` instead:

```
m5 <- cbind(mapply("-", m1[,idx], mea[idx,]), m1[,-idx])
```

Now if we look at `head(m5[,c(1,2)])` we see:

```
    4 17
1   NA NA
2   NA NA
3   NA NA
4 10.5 NA
5 -4.5 NA
6 -3.5 NA
```

Or that `7.5` is being correctly subtracted from the entire first column. If you check the second column you can also see that `19.5` is being correctly subtracted from the entire column

Comment: Thank you @Mike H.! That's it! And thank's for the explanation as well. That  helped a lot.